# What's the correct way to submit a form using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

So I'm writing a form and I'm currently writing the submit function. This submit function should check the form is valid, POST it to the server and then when the response is received change state using ui-router.

All fairly simple stuff, though it got me thinking. In most examples of AngularJS, I see the following:

```
$scope.submit = function() {
    var params = { someKey: $scope.someKey };
    $http.post(...);
};
```

To me, this seems backwards.. doesn't this couple `$scope.submit` heavily to the current state of `$scope` ergo making that hard(er) to test?

I recently wrote something along these lines:

```
$scope.submit = function(params) {
    // Any sanity checking, such as checking various parameters exist
    if(angular.isUndefined(params.summonerName)) {
        throwToysOutOfPram();
        return;
    }
    $http.post(...);
};
```

And then in the view, I have something like this:

```
<button ng-click='submit({ summonerName: summonerName, twitchName: twitchName })'>Submit</button>
```

To me, this seems to make the most sense from a testability POV but there's part of me that feels bad about putting that 'logic' in the view. What is the general consensus?

---

### `AddStreamerCtrl`

```
angular.module('project.streamers')
.controller('AddStreamerCtrl', ['$scope', 'channelName', 'Streamer', 'regions', 'languages', function ($scope, channelName, Streamer, regions, languages) {
    $scope.channelName = channelName;
    $scope.regions = regions;
    $scope.languages = languages;

    $scope.submit = function(params) {
        Streamer.save(params, function() {
            console.log('it worked!');
        }, function() { 
            console.error('something went wrong :(');
        });
    };
}]);
```

### `streamers.add` state setup

```
angular.module('project.streamers')
.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('streamers.add', {
        templateUrl: '/streamers/create.html',
        url: '/add',
        params: {
            channelName: null,
        },
        controller: 'AddStreamerCtrl',
        resolve: {
            channelName: function($stateParams) {
                return $stateParams.channelName;
            },
            languages: function(Language) {
                return Language.get();
            },
            regions: function(Region) {
                return Region.get();
            }
        }
    }); 
}]);
```

### create.html

```
<h1>Streamer Sign Up</h1>
<p>This form will guide you through the steps of adding your stream to our list. In order to qualify, you must have a valid League of Legends and Twitch account.</p>

<p class='panel callout'>Please note that the administrators of this website reserve the right to remove your stream at their discretion.</p>

<form name='addStreamerForm' ng-submit='submit(data)'>
    <label>Twitch Channel 
        <input type="text" ng-model='data.channelName' name="channelName" placeholder="Channel Name" required>
    </label>
    <p>This is your Twitch username. For example, if your url is <code>twitch.tv/aredherring</code>, then your username would be <code>aredherring</code>.</p>

    <label>Language
        <select ng-options='language.id as language.name for language in languages' ng-model='data.language' required>
            <option value=''>Select a language</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <p>This is the language you stream in. If you are multi-lingual, please select the language you will use most often.</p>

    <label>Region 
        <select ng-options='region.id as region.name for region in regions' ng-model='data.region' required>
            <option value=''>Select a region</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <p>This is the region your League of Legends account is on. If you have accounts on multiple regions, select the region you are most likely to play on on a day-to-day basis.</p>

    <label>Summoner Name
        <input type="text" name="summonerName" ng-model='data.summonerName' placeholder="Summoner Name" required>
    </label>
    <p>This is your summoner name for your League of Legends account. If you have multiple accounts, specify the account that you use most often.</p>

    <p>We will use the League of Legends API and Twitch API to retrieve data about your accounts.</p>


    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="tAndCs">
        I agree to the <a ui-sref='termsAndConditions'>Terms and Conditions</a>
    </label>

    <input type='submit' class='button' value='Submit'>
</form>
```

Comment: It really doesn't seem like you are tapping into using ng-model to your benefit properly and the angular built in validation API. Perhaps showing a few fields worth of markup would help. Also you aren't taking advantage of `ng-submit` on the form

Comment: It's a contrived example to show a point, but I'll expand in a little while

Comment: Point is lost on me, looks like you are trying to re-invent the wheel

Comment: What do you mean by "testability"? Testability of the parameters on the front-end? [Unit-testing](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing) of the angular module? [End to end](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/e2e-testing) testing?

Comment: I meant is it bad practise to access $scope from within $scope.submit() (in this example)

Comment: In this example, I don't think it matters either way. They're equally good and equally testable.

Comment: If you've never seen this presentation about the 1.3 form  API upgrades, well worth watching http://www.yearofmoo.com/2014/09/taming-forms-in-angularjs-1-3.html

Comment: Should be a good watch for some late night procrastinating, thank you @charlietfl

Comment: The guy who put it together started working on forms on his own, angular (google) liked it so much they hired him. I think it will open eyes to a lot more power under the hood

Comment: I will be the first to admit I used 1.2.X in my previous job. I am only just coming back to 1.3.X now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an effort to maintain low [coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29) and high [cohesion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)) in software development, it is generally good practice to separate functionality from the data it manipulates as much as possible, so it can be used for more than one instance of a data set. In which case yes, the second method you outline above is more desirable, because it's not tied to the specific variables attached to `$scope`.

Assuming you had an `ng-model="data.summonerName"` and `ng-model="data.twitchName"`, you could do:

```
<button ng-click='submit(data)'>Submit</button>
```

This way, if you discover later that (for instance) you need to be able to call submit from the code itself (or some [unit-testing](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing) code), you can do so very easily:

```
$scope.submit({summonerName: testSummonerName, twitchName: testTwitchName});
```

With the original method, you would have to do some funky manipulation of the `$scope` properties.

Also, with Angular, form validation can be done almost entirely in the markup, and provides immediate responses to user input (see their **[forms guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)**).

> Keep in mind that while client-side validation plays an important role
>   in providing good user experience, it can easily be circumvented and
>   thus can not be trusted. Server-side validation is still necessary for
>   a secure application.

Comment: But scope shouldn't have a bunch of variables, rather it should contain models. In angular best practice `ng-model` should always have a dot in it (prototypical inheritance).  The whole set of form data would then be represented by a single object on the scope and `ng-model` will even add the properties if they don't already exits. No need to add a bunch of arguments to the submit function then either

Comment: @charlietfl Forgive me if I am ignorant here but how does me putting everything in a single object via `ng-model='data.X'` (which I will do) change my approach on passing the arguments into `$scope.submit(data)` rather than using `$scope.submit = function() { /* access $scope.data here */ }`?

Comment: There's no need to add those arguments in the markup when everything is already available as a single object in the controller is my point. You have the ng-model, and the ng-form  object which has all the validation methods/properties

Comment: @charlietfl Good point about representing the form data as a single object on the scope.

Comment: But then that makes my method intrinsically linked to the object on the scope, which is what I am concerned about. When it comes to unit tests, now I have to mock up `$scope.data` (because the function accesses `$scope.data`) rather than passing in parameters directly into the function, like my example does (note that my original example passed in a single params object, unlike what NanoWizard has suggested)

Comment: And what's the difference between mocking the params in function arguments vs passing mock data to controller?

Comment: @DanPantry Actually it is not intrinsically linked to the object on the scope. You could just as easily call `$scope.submit({summonerName: otherSummonerName, twitchName: otherTwitchName})` which is not tied to the `$scope.data` at all.

Comment: I think there's some miscommunication going on here. I said I wanted to use `$scope.submit({})`. The vibe I was getting was that @charlietfl et al wanted me to use `$scope.submit()` and access `$scope.data` from within that. I had no confusion you agreed with me on using `$scope.submit({})`, @NanoWizard

Comment: @DanPantry Yes sorry, I misunderstood your comment to mean that `$scope.submit({})` tied the submit function to the scope. I realize now that that's not what you meant.